# Is it correct to use a 1/3 arc-second DEM to make a 2 ft contour shapefile?

Tags: dem, contour, usgs

I need 2ft contours for all of Puerto Rico. I have downloaded 1/3 arc-second DEM on the island from the USGS. Would it even be accurate I if I just made these in ArcGIS Pro? All alternatives and suggestions are welcome!

****(I know how to make the contour lines, but I am asking about accuracy and best practices)****

Comment: A 1/9 arc second DEM would get you closer if available in your area of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the goal the contours are supposed to serve. ⅓ arc sec is about 10M or 33', so the accuracy of your contours is limited by that resolution. In steep terrain (100% grade), a single pixel in the DEM might contain 15  2' contour lines. Where these are drawn will be a function of the interpolation algorithm, not the actual underlying topography. Similarly, on nearly flat ground, you might miss local areas that should be surrounded by a contour line.

A higher resolution DEM reduces the scale over which these phenomena occur.

My gut reaction is that if you are asking to know vertical information to a resolution of 2', you want a comparable or better horizontal resolution of where that measurement applies to.